# ImportExportModelAdmin gives error django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: admin/import_export/change_list_import_export.html

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i am trying to make admin panel such that services and service_price must appear on same page Like this
[image]

And As Clicking on Services on django admin panel I am getting this error

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 65, in resolve_template
    return get_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: admin/import_export/change_list_import_export.html
```

Here is my Code:

> Admin.py:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class ServicePriceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ServicesPrice

@admin.register(Services)
class ServicesAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ServicePriceInline
    ]
    search_fields = ['service_name']
```

Models.py:

```
class Services(models.Model):
    service_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,related_name='sub_service')
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    service_icon = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    service_image = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    service_description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class ServicesPrice(models.Model):
    price_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    service_id = models.ForeignKey(Services,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant_id = models.ForeignKey(Variant,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    price_description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
    discount_percentage = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    discount_amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    active_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue too. It turned out that I had forgotten to add `'import_export',` to INSTALLED_APPS in my settings.py. Once I added this the template loader was able to find the template.

If you don't see the import_export module added to INSTALLED_APPS try adding it.

Comment: Works well, doesn't it? Happy that you like the concept.